# Remove string between characters

Tags: java, regex

I would like to remove everything(for the chars like `{}$* \w+ ""`) which is between `;` and `#`:

For example I would like to remove from this string:

**Input:**

`OR(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;ABZZ/kld // remove ;M10#`

**Output:**

`OR(AND(CA18*CB18);ABZZ/kld`

I tried it with this regular expression:

`^[;]\w+([A-Za-z0-9])[#]`

However, this does not seem to work any recommendations?

Comment: can you define "everything"? does it include multiple `;` and/or `#` inside the removed string? or any characters other than those 2? or just any word characters?

Comment: @deathApril Thx for your answer! Mostly the strings will have this chars in it: `M$10, {, }, *, $`

Comment: what would be expected output for `OR(M1;M2#;M#3;M4)`?

Comment: `OR(M1;M2#;M#3;M4)` would be `OR(M13;M4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solution for your updated question would be:

```
// the actual regex is ;[{}$*\w"']+?#, but extra escaping is needed for Java:
input.replaceAll(";[{}$*\\w\"']+?#", "");
```

where you can update the character set between [] to match your actual requirements as you discover more edge cases..

if you decided you need a black-list of characters instead, you could use expression with negated character set (`^` inside [], do not confuse with ^ at the start of a regex, which denotes the beginning of a string):

```
;[^;#]+?#
```

Comment: Got the error `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )` for your answer! Pls update it!

Comment: `"` needs a single backslash though (see the syntax highlighting of your answer).

Comment: @sp00m ah, I will never understand how people can work with regexes in Java. syntax highlighting in SO looked fine, I guess Java would have different opinion about that, updated again.

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution:

```
String input = "OR(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;ABZZ/kld"; // remove ;M10#
// using String.replaceAll here instead of Pattern/Matcher
//
//                                   | starts with ; included
//                                   || any character, reluctantly quantified
//                                   ||  | ends with # included
//                                   ||  |   | replace all instances with empty
//                                   ||  |   | string
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(";.+?#", ""));
```

**Output**

```
OR(AND(CA18*CB18);ABZZ/kld
```

Comment: note this solution will also remove `;M10;M11#` - not sure if that is expected by OP.

Comment: Yep right. Just added a definition of everything to my answer! Would appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 4):

- `^` means "start of the string", i.e. your string must start with `;`, which is not the case (it starts with `O`).
- `\w+([A-Za-z0-9])` is quite redundant: `\w` is actually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, so unless you really need this `_` distinction, `\w+` should be enough

So, simply try with: `;\w+#`

---

If you need any char between `;` and `#` (i.e. not only `[A-Za-z0-9_]`): `;[^;#]+#`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3M_Cp5xPkGYUyEmA)

Comment: +1 for explaining the meaning of `^` and simplifying regexp. (You could add an explanation of `$` for completeness thou).

Comment: THX for this great explanation! Just added a definition of "everything". Would appreciate it if you add this to your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex only accepts two non symbol characters

```
;[A-z0-9]*?#
```

Will grab anything in between. The same regex with a `+` instead of the `*` will only match instances with at least on char in between the symbols.

Comment: THx for your answer! `text = text.replaceAll("^;[A-z0-9]*?#", "");` does not seem to do the job ;(

Comment: The non greedy `*?` cardinality is useless in this case.

Comment: It has been updated without the `^`. Should work then.   Also the non greedy `*` was used in order to prevent cases in where there are more than one pairs of symbols, to avoid replacing everything between the two.

Comment: @AdamYost Yeah, but since the only allowed chars are `[A-z0-9]`, there won't be any other inner matched symbol.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
 String sURL = "OR(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;ABZZ/kld";
 System.out.println(sURL.replaceAll(";\\w+?#", ""));
```

Comment: Why only `\w`? He asks for "everything".

Comment: Thx for your answer! I tried it with a different character combination in between like `$, /, (, *`, however `\w+` only matches alphanumeric characters. Any recommendations to match all chars in between?

Comment: @JamieCockburn It is not defined what everything meas. so i guess from the tried expression of OR that thare can only be word character

Comment: @Kare sURL.replaceAll(";.+?#", "") sould do it. But i have not tried it

Comment: @Jens Just put a definition of "everything" in my question. Btw your string replaces more than it should, because some string look like that: `;M10#;CA18*CB18/$M$10;I`, which result in `""`

Comment: @Kare I have tried it by my own and got :`;CA18*CB18/$M$10;I`

Comment: @Jens Sorry, just showed a small amount of the string: Please also try it on this one: `=IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY18=4;AND(CA18*CB18);$M$10#/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12` you will get: `=IF(AND($BY18=2)/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12`

Comment: Now it is a little bit dificult. But try `      String sURL = "=IF(AND($BY18=2);CA18*CB18/$M$11;IF(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;CA18*CB18/$M$10;IF($BY1‌​8=4;AND(CA18*CB18);$M$10#/$M$9;CA18*CB18)))/$M$12";
      sURL  = new StringBuilder(sURL).reverse().toString();
      sURL = sURL.replaceAll("#.+?;", "");
      sURL = new StringBuilder(sURL).reverse().toString();
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
[^;]*?#;
```

Comment: Pls explain, what does it do?

Comment: It will remove any occurance of character or digits between ; and #.    Eg: OR(AND(CA18*CB18);M10#;ABZZ/kld will remove ;M10#